Extracting logfiles in RINEX format from eSA2-device for post-processing
I am measuring locations in a forest in Germany with the eSA2. This device can use the RTK correction. Due to the bad reception i don't have internet sometimes and can't use RTK. I know it is possible to save log-files and use those to do post processing, which will correct your position afterwards.
Currently I am using the app GPSTest to save the logfiles on my Android tablet. I configured in the settings that it should save everything (NMEA, Measurements, GnssStatus, Orientation, Location, Navigation messages). The output file is a .txt file, but apparently I need it to be in the RINEX-format. The FAQ of GPSTest provides a link to a script called Android_RINEX that was written to format the txt file into a RINEX-file. I have managed to install it and am using the example command
gnsslogger_to_rnx my_data.txt 2> test

However it doesn't work and gives me the following output:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gnsslogger_to_rnx", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('andrnx==0.1', 'gnsslogger_to_rnx')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 656, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1460, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/andrnx-0.1-py3.10.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/gnsslogger_to_rnx", line 68, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/andrnx-0.1-py3.10.egg/andrnx/gnsslogger.py", line 186, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/andrnx-0.1-py3.10.egg/andrnx/gnsslogger.py", line 107, in __init__
AttributeError: type object 'GnssLogHeader' has no attribute 'parse_'. Did you mean: 'parse_fix'?

I am not at all good with python and I think I have reached my capabilities. So i have the following questions:
Am I using the right Apps to get RINEX data for post-processing?
Is the device capable of providing logfiles for post-processing?
What am i doing wrong with the android_rinex script?
I provided a example log-file here.
